# split a word in pandas and create new column

Tags: pandas, split

I have a column with random texts, I need to filter a word in it by creating a new column.

for example in this case I want to filter the word "Shanghai" to new column.

Can you help me plesase?

```
data={"A":"Shanghai : 101-150 (Univ ); QS : 314 (Univ ); THE : 351-400 (Univ ); Webometrics : 19 (Univ )","B":"Webometrics : 96 (Nom propre ); Shanghai Thématique","C":"Webometrics : 164 "}


df=pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['Index', 'legend'])
df
```

[the output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86cLv.png)

Comment: so you filter the word shangai, then what? can you show an example output

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: the output is new column with "yes"/ "no"
* yes if found "shanghai" in legend*

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to use np.where and determine if a specific word is in the column

```
word_legend = 'Shanghai'
df['Text Found'] = np.where(df.legend.str.contains(word_legend ), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: No problem, man, if you liked your answer upvote and mark as answered so others can come later and know the answers to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish it

```
word = 'Shanghai'
df['text_found'] = df['legend'].str.contains(word)
df
```

```
    Index   legend  text_found
0   A   Shanghai : 101-150 (Univ ); QS : 314 (Univ ); ...   True
1   B   Webometrics : 96 (Nom propre ); Shanghai Théma...   True
2   C   Webometrics : 164   False
```